# How to get data out of an array list by using the String

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

i have an array list here :

```
 ArrayList <vehicles> carsArray = new ArrayList<vehicles>();
    carsArray.add(new vehicles ("CAR","Peugot","3008",12500.00));
    carsArray.add(new vehicles ("CAR","BMW","316",4995.00));
    carsArray.add(new vehicles ("CAR","Ford","Fiesta",12995.00));

    carsArray.add(new vehicles ("VAN","P","3008",22500.00));
    carsArray.add(new vehicles ("VAN","B","316",24995.00));
    carsArray.add(new vehicles ("VAN","F","Fiesta",22995.00));
```

what i want to do is go through this array list and only get the vans out. is there a way to loop through the array and if the vehicle type is "van" print that out to console.

Thanks

Comment: Got a lot to choose from. You really should follow java naming conventions and make class names start with a capital letter. i.e. Vehicles, not vehicles. Good question, though a google search may have give you hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be something like :

```
for(int i=0; i<carsArray.size(); i++) {
    if(carsArray.get(i).getType().equals("VAN")
        System.out.println(carsArray.get(i).getModel());
}
```

This is assuming that the Vehicle class looks something like :

```
class Vehicle {
    String type;
    String brand;
    String model;
    String speed;

    private String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    private String setType(String vehType) {
        type = vehType;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Me and you posted like the exact same thing. Thumbs up! ;)

Comment: Thumbs up to you too! (:

Answer (score 1):

In `vehicles` class you should have a *getter* for that String, then you can easily check if the the object has "VAN" String or something else.

```
class Vehicles {
  ...
  ...

   public boolean isVan() {
       return "VAN".equals(myType);
   }

}
```

Please follow the Java naming conventions and change the class name to begin with capital letter.

Comment: I would've suggested that VAN is a part of an enum, but that's out of scope

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. ArrayLists can use advanced `for` loops like arrays. Do this:

```
for (vehicles vehicle : carsArray) {
    if (vehicle.getType().equals("VAN")) { //Assuming get type method exists
         System.out.println("Vehicle " + vehicle.getName() + " is a van");
    }
}
```

Or if you need indexes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vehicle.size(); i++) {
    if (carsArray.get(i).getType().equals("VAN")) {
        System.out.println("Vehicle at index " + i + " is a van.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (vehicles vehicles : carsArray) {
    if(vehicles.getS1().equalsIgnoreCase("Van")) {
        System.out.println(vehicles);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(vehicles v:  carsArray) {
    // v is vehicle obj inside carsArray
    // you can check the desired condition here
}
```